# Android - Interact with an other activity

Tags: android, events

So, I've got a question !

I have got an activity called X. When the user click on a button, the activity Y is displayed.
I want that this activity can be closed after have received an event sent by activity X.

Do you know how can I do this ?

Comment: keep in mind that ActivityX can no longer exists when ActivityY is displayed ...

Comment: it does it exist, just that it's not visible to the user

Comment: no ... it can be killed ... even if you can back to it(back stack), it doesn't mean that it will be the same instance ...it can be reacreated ...

Comment: activityX is exists if developer does not call finish() while activityY is starting. its window focues state changes.

Comment: yes, it can be killed if he goes and uses up the memory from other apps. But still!

Comment: But still! ... is better to use Service for such things ... and do not asume that more than one Activity can be running/active at the same time

Comment: I don't understand. What is the difference between destroying an Activity from a Service or from another Activity?

Comment: @Cranal because Activity in Paused/Stopped **cannot execute any code.** http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html ... when ActivityY becomes visible ActivityX gets Paused/Stopped state ... thats why for example we should dissable broadcast recivers in onPause and enable it again on onResume of Activity

Comment: Activities on the back stack will not be reclaimed on low memory conditions unless your application's entire process is killed (and in this case your whole app dies, not only the non-visible activities). Memory management on Android happens at a process level, so Android will kill *processes* in the background not activities. Yes the documentation seems to indicate that it is the case but in fact it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a `BroadcastMessage` from X. In y register a `BroadcastReceiver` with same `IntentFilter`. So from x you can send a predefined exit message which will be catched by y activity's `onReceive` method. There you can end the activity Y.

**For Example:**

**in Y activity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("exit")) {
                finish();

            }
        }
    }
```

dont forget to register the receiver

```
    registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Constants.YOUR_INTENT_FILTER));
```

and unregister

```
unregisterReceiver( mMessageReceiver);
```

**IN X activity:**

```
send the broadcastmessage using `sendBroadcast(Intent i)`
```

For this kind of internal messaging I prefer [LocalBoradcastManager](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html&ei=sFxtUdyILIfKrAeCz4CYBg&usg=AFQjCNFu8jEI2XY2MXPdmzmaudH4M_XsBg&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bmk)

Comment: partally correct ... sendBroadcast(Intent i) should not be called from ActivityX but from Service(started from ActivityX before ActivityY is started)

Comment: @Selvin. what if ther eis no service? I can directly call from activity ( I used localbroadcastmanager)

Comment: @Selvin: why from a Service? And why do you think he started the Activity Y from a Service? He said, he started Activity Y from Activity X.

Comment: @Carnal activity state: Paused
In this state, the activity is partially obscured by another activity—the other activity that's in the foreground is semi-transparent or doesn't cover the entire screen. The paused activity does not receive user input and **cannot execute any code.** from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: @Selvin: I need to test this, I'm sure I've been able to execute code with receiver on paused activities.

Comment: @Selving.. you better check. because I have done this in so many tasks

Comment: @StinePike so you had made it wrong ... even if you are able to do it, you shouldn't

Comment: @Selvin: You're wrong mate, I did a test updating even the GUI when the Activity was onPause, and it works fine ;)

Comment: you so wrong ... for example: we can avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException by dissabling StrictMode ... but should we ? No! ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259907/android-can-background-activities-execute-code

Comment: Lets give a post.. you guys post a question if you are free. or I will post when I am free

Comment: So how do you explain this answer and all the up votes and the comments below the accepted answer? Here mate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not have two activities "running" at the same time.  Activity X goes through its end of lifecycle when you start Activity Y.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

> Each time a new activity starts, the previous activity is stopped, but the system preserves the activity in a stack (the "back stack"). When a new activity starts, it is pushed onto the back stack and takes user focus. The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" stack mechanism, so, when the user is done with the current activity and presses the Back button, it is popped from the stack (and destroyed) and the previous activity resumes. (The back stack is discussed more in the Tasks and Back Stack document.)

Answer (score 0):

- When you receive `BroadcastMessage` from `ActivityX` then  you can set value of one Global `boolean`
- you should check  that value of bolean at the time of use of `Activity Y`(it may in `onCreate` )
  in `Activity Y`
- if you get this boolean value `true`(or whatever you set at the time of call `BroadcastMessage` ) then simply call `finish()`

> The thing is android not running two activity at the same time , so 
>   without having activity  you can not finish it remotely